# Are there any physics reasons why the avoid-phase-transition technique used to make aerogel can't be done with a human immersed in xenon gas?

Tags: pressure, phase-transition, density, inert-gases

This question relates to [this earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/681192/what-physics-could-be-applied-to-accelerate-a-person-from-zero-to-8000-m-s-if-yo) about what clever physics might be useful for subjecting a human to extremely high accelerations without damaging them.

The specific idea here is similar to liquid breathing, but it would use pressurized xenon gas. The subject would be placed in a form fitting coffin, xenon would be pumped in until the density of the air (mostly xenon at this point) reached the density of the human body. This compressed xenon-air would fill the subject's lungs and prevent lung collapse during the extremely high-gee acceleration. Then, immediately after the acceleration, the xenon would be removed while maintaining the partial pressure of the oxygen and nitrogen in the air. We should assume that we have some means of conditioning the air temperature during the whole process.

I acknowledge that there may be potential physiological problems with this idea - I will ask the medical community about those later.

The question for this community is, "Does this proposed technique violate any known laws of physics?"

Comment: Why not just use breathing fluid a la "The Abyss," and is a lot closer to human densities than pressurized gas

Comment: I read (long ago - I don't know where) about a mouse that breathed water supersaturated with oxygen. It worked for a short time. But lungs are not built for such a dense fluid. They collapsed after a few minutes.

Comment: @triatticus If I recall, that liquid is roughly twice the density of the human body. Plus, it would be very unpleasant for the to the traveler to have to switch to and from breathing an actual liquid.

Comment: I don't remember where I read it, but I think I read that enough pressure is toxic, in and of itself, no matter what you are breathing. The pressure alters the chemistry of certain crucial proteins. It's kind of like how heavy water is toxic even though you'd expect it's chemistry to be exactly like that of ordinary water. Biochemistry is subtle and sophisticated.

Comment: @phil1008, there was [an episode of U.F.O.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0735629/?ref_=ttep_ep19) that dealt with that exact problem.

Comment: @SolomonSlow one wouldn't expect heavy water to be the same as water since isotopes are even just slightly chemically different. The reason for heavy water toxicity isn't pressure but the stronger humydrogen bonds between the heavy water molecules.